# How do I give the user two options for which code to run?

Tags: java, if-statement

So I am trying to get a calculation depending on what the user inputs. Like:

```
if (game1.equalsIgnoreCase ("Bama"));
player = player + 10;
player2 = player2 + 10;
if (game1.equalsIgnoreCase ("OSU"));
player = player + 20;
player2 = player 2 + 20;
```

This is adding both up at the same time, no matter when I put in (OSU or Bama). How do I only get it to run only one of them?

(I am new to Java, as well as this website, so forgive me if this isn't a clean question.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- You are making a single if statement
- You are not including both instructions on your if block.

The fixed code should be the following:

```
if (game1.equalsIgnoreCase ("Bama")){
    player = player + 10; 
    player2 = player2 + 10; 
}
if (game1.equalsIgnoreCase ("OSU")){
    player = player + 20; 
    player2 = player 2 + 20;
}
```

Comment: Maybe an `else if` would be better (`game1` cannot assume both the values in any case), even though the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
If(game1.equalsIgnoreCase("Bama")){
player=player+10;
player2=player2+10;
}else if(game1.equalsIgnorCase("OSU"){
Player=player+20;
player2=player2+20;
}
```